# C# SqlConnection AttachDbFile does not recognize file path

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am new to C#, so forgive me for asking. I am trying to write a `SqlConnection` but the following code shows a red scribbly line where the db path begins. I have already copied the path from the database's connection string. It has given me lots of headache. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="D:\projects\Clinic POS\Clinic POS\Inventory.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the quotes around the file name:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\projects\Clinic POS\Clinic POS\Inventory.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much sir! i new there was something i was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\projects\\Clinic POS\\Clinic POS\\Inventory.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```